# How to align a div so it begins at the center of a sibling span element

Tags: html, css

I have a `span` element of a font-awesome icon and and a `<div>` element that contains text. I want the text to always begin at the center of the icon.

HTML

```
//Font awesome icon within a circle
<span class="fa-stack fa-2x type-icon">
    <span class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x circle"></span>
    <span class="info fas fa-info fa-stack-1x"></span>
</span>
<div class="content mb-0">content text goes here</div>
```

CSS

```
.type-icon {
  font-size: 1.0rem;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: left;
}

.content {
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

Comment: to allow `vertical-align`, use `display:inline-block` instead of `float`. span and div cannot be sibblings, btw

Comment: @G-Cyr Why couldn't they be siblings ? `div>div+span` is correct.

Comment: Div and span are both neutral html element. One is inline ,  the other is a block. Span can be à child of div, not à sibbling nor a parent. That is basic html rule since almost ever :)

Comment: @G-Cyr i did with you said, but `vertical-align` still puts the div with the text to lineup with the image, I need it to start from the center

Comment: remenber, span is inline and div is block, to vertical-align them side by side, it requires both to be inline-block and small enough to stand on the same line ;)